# How to get a hotkey (ctrl + n) to run with subprocess (VLC) in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, vlc

I am making a python application that creates a rtsp link of a local DVR (based on the information that it's given through input), It's 90% complete and there's just one more step left. After the link generation, VLC media player will be opened (which is how far i have got).Then in VLC media player, CTRL+ n will be automatically pressed so that a new window can open, in which the RTSP link will be inserted so that the DVR camera feed will automatically play in VLC media player.
**I am stuck on the hotkey part...In which CTRL+ n will be automatically pressed after VLC has started. If someone knows about it then please help me.**
MY CODE:

```
#Import libaries
import os
import platform  #To identify the OS
import subprocess  #To start VLC
import keyboard  #keyboard module (not working)
from pynput import keyboard  #keyboard module (not working)
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from subprocess import DEVNULL    # To keep the script running after subprocess is called

#DVR inputs
ip_adr = input("What is your DVR's ip address?: ")
port = input("What is your DVR's RTSP port? (it should be 554 or else): ")
username = input("What is your DVR's username? (The default is admin): ")
password = input("What is your DVR's password?: ")
linkurl = "rtsp://" + username +":" + password + "@" + ip_adr + ":" + port +"/Streaming/channels/1/"

#Identify OS
nameos = platform.system()

if nameos == "Linux":  # For Linux
    cmd='vlc';
    print("Your DVR rtsp link is: " + linkurl)
    Popen([cmd], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
else:   # For windows
    cmd='vlc';
    print("Your DVR rtsp link is: " + linkurl)
    Popen([cmd], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
```

Don't run it using the terminal or command prompt. Run it using VS Code terminal (i recommend from here) or directly as interpreter and make sure to have VLC installed.

Comment: Directly open using arguments. Just tried `vlc rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov` and it works not platform independent though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, [VLC's command line args](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line#Receiving_a_network_stream) can start a network stream directly by supplying an `rtsp://` link:

> To receive a RTSP stream, start VLC with:
>
> `% vlc rtsp://www.example.org/your_stream`